# Django Prefetch related_name not visible when using multiple lookup

Tags: django, database

When i use the django Prefetch object (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-objects) on multiple fields like this:

```
model_a.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch(model_b__model_c), to_attr='data')
```

where model_a has a m2m relation to model_b and model_c has a foreign key of model_b. 
I don't seem to get the 'data' field on the elements of the returned QuerySet.

Am I looking in the wrong place maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, based on the relationships you describe, the `Prefetch` object would need to be constructed like this (unless you have defined a `related_name` for the relationships, in which case you need the related name without appending `_set`):

```
Prefetch('model_b_set__model_c_set')
```

Second, you are in fact doing two prefetches:

- The first one fetches all `model_b` instances for every `model_a`.
- The second one fetches all `model_c` instances for every `model_b`.

`data` is defined for the second prefetch, ie. on `model_b` instances, not on `model_a`, and it will contain a list of `model_c` instances. So you'd access it like this:

```
a_models = ModelA.objects.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('model_b_set__model_c_set'), 
    to_attr='data')
for a in a_models:
    for b in a.model_b_set.all():
        b.data # => contains a list of model_c instances
```